# Can't disable editing for a column in DT table

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

My shiny app has an editable table (DT).
The user defines some parameters, including the number of columns of the table. The app creates a matrix with normal samples using some parameters directly stablished by the user and others calculated in the code (calculations that I don't show here).

At first, as the goal is to create an example for the user, the matrix created has two calculated columns (the first and the last).
It renders this matrix as a table, and it accept editions by row.
As the user edits the table, the last column recalculates reactively (the first doesn't and it's ok).

***As the last column is always calculated, I wanted to disable editing for it, but I can't do it... As far as I noticed, the only thing it's different in my code, in comparison to the example in the link, is that I use reactive objects... is it a problem?***

***Note: When I run the app in the link, it works.***

The link: https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


dt_output = function(title, id, button_id) {
  fluidRow(
    column(
      12, 
      h1(title),
      hr(), 
      DTOutput(id),
      actionButton(button_id, "Delete data")
    )
  )
}


render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}


generate_normal_data <- function(n, mi, sigma, LI, LS) {
 vetor_nomes_col <- "Yd"
 vetor_nomes_col[n+2] <- "S2"
 
 vetor_nomes_col[1:n+1] <- paste("X", seq(from=1,to=n), sep = "")

 result_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 100, ncol = n + 2)

 #Code that returns a matrix with normal samples in "n" columns + two calculated columns (the first and the last)

 colnames(result_matrix) <- vetor_nomes_col

 return(result_matrix)

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "sandstone"),
  
  titlePanel("Simulador B-ATTRIVAR SS S2"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("n", "n"),
      numericInput("t","t"),
      numericInput("r","r"),
      numericInput("e","e"),
      numericInput("w","w"),
      numericInput("l","l"),
      numericInput("b","b"),
      actionButton("runButton", "Execute")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Results and Chart",
                 
                 tableOutput("results"),
                 plotOutput("chart")),
        tabPanel("Insert data", 
                 dt_output('Double-click to edit table cells', 'x1', 'deleteButton'),
                 actionButton("plotDataButton", "Plot Data")),
        
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  d1 <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)
  
 #Edition
  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
    
    d1$ults <<- editData(d1$ults, input$x1_cell_edit, 'x1', rownames = FALSE, resetPaging = FALSE)
        
    d1$ults[input$x1_cell_edit$row[1], (req(input$n) + 2)] <<- var(as.numeric(d1$ults[input$x1_cell_edit$row[1], 2:(req(input$n) + 1)]))
    
    
    replaceData(proxy = dataTableProxy("x1"), d1$ults, resetPaging = FALSE)    

})


  observeEvent(input$deleteButton, {
    d1$ults[] <- NA 
    output$x1 = render_dt(d1$ults, list(target = 'row', disable = list(columns = (req(input$n) + 2))))
  })

  res <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)
  res2 <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$runButton, {

  #code that calculates a vector
  calculated_vector <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)

  res$ults <- calculated_vector

  d1$ults <- generate_normal_data(input$n, input$mi, input$sigma, req(res$ults[[6]]), req(res$ults[[7]]))

})

  output$x1 = render_dt(
    req(d1$ults),list(target = 'row', disable = list(columns = as.integer(ncol(req(d1$ults)))))
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, e.g. `could not find function "bs_theme"` or `Error in numericInput("n", "n") :  argument "value" is missing, with no default`. You should edit it in order to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).